# Using generic relations in handling images and file of the project

Tags: django-rest-framework

my problem is that i understand how to use generic relation but can't perform it onto uploading multiple images in serializers

i tried to use generic relation in uploading media of the project (files or images) but with no luck i don't know how to make my serializer i tried to follow up with the example of bookmarks and taggeditem but still confused

```
class ImageHandler(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(blank=True,upload_to='images/')
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to='images/')
    TYPE_CHOICES    =   (
        ('files',   'Files'),
        ('images',  'Images'),
    )
    file_type   =   models.CharField(max_length=10,
            choices=TYPE_CHOICES,
            )
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

```
class Branch(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True,null=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyData,related_name='company_branch',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=230)
    status  =   models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at  =   models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at  =   models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    images = GenericRelation(ImageHandler)
```

```
class ImageObjectRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Branch):
            serializers = ImageSerializer
            # serializer = BranchSerializer(value)
        else:
            raise Exception('Unexpected type of tagged object')

        return serializer.data

class BranchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only = True)

    images = ImageObjectRelatedField(many=True, queryset=ImageHandler.objects.all())
    company = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=CompanyData.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Branch
        fields = ('id','title','phone','location','company','status','images')
```

i expect to upload multiple images or files related to specific model

Comment: No answer yet ??

Comment: No answer yet ??